# Изменение регистра заголовка при использовании prefersLargeTitles

Tags: swift4, navigationbar, ios11

Я знаю что можно задать шрифт, цвет, размер шрифта отдельно для "больших" и "маленьких" заголовков при использовании prefersLargeTitles.

Но можно ли, при включенном "LargeTitles" у навигационного контроллера добиться, чтобы "большой заголовок" на "развернутой" навигационной панели показывался символами в верхнем регистре?

Т.е. добиться вот такого эффекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас для этой цели использую кастомный Navigation Controller:

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    public var titleSaved: String?

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        guard let topItem = navigationBar.topItem else {
            return
        }

        if navigationBar.frame.size.height > 60 {
            topItem.title = topItem.title?.uppercased()
        } else {
            if let titleSaved = titleSaved {
                topItem.title = titleSaved
            } else {
                topItem.title = topItem.title?.applyingTransform(StringTransform(rawValue: "Title"), reverse: false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

установка заголовка из View Controller'а:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        let title = "Sign In"
        navigationItem.title = title

        if let nc = navigationController as? MyNavigationController {
            nc.titleSaved = title
        }
    }

}
```

Это решение работает, но при переходе от "большого" заголовка к "маленькому" и обратно, он немного дергается - выглядит это не очень красиво ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, у attributed string нет такого ключа, чтобы устанавливать регистр. Да и largе title имеют довольно скудный набор для настройки, наверняка чтобы смотрелось унифицированно от приложения к приложению.

Если Вам нужно менять только регистр заголовка, сделайте свой элемент со сходным поведением, но необходимыми возможностями.

Если нужны и остальные преимущества, необходимо отслеживать текущее состояние и в зависимости от этого менять title.

---

Вариант с KVO и UILabel как titleView, но под задачу думаю Вам подойдет. Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для начала нам нужно найти часть, отвечающую за Large Title и затем наблюдать за изменениями. Полный пример:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var observing: NSKeyValueObservation?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureTitle()
    }

    func configureTitle() {
        //: Настраиваете шрифт/размер как угодно
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        //: - Устанавливаем начальный заголовок как текст кастомного titleView
        titleLabel.text = navigationItem.title
        navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
        //: - Делаем заголовок большими буквами для Large Title
        navigationItem.title = navigationItem.title?.uppercased()
        let largeTitleView = navigationController?.navigationBar.getLargeTitleView()
        observing = largeTitleView?.observe(\.alpha, options: [.new], changeHandler: { [weak titleLabel] (label, value) in
            if let alpha = value.newValue {
                titleLabel?.alpha = alpha.isZero ? 1 : 0
            }
        })
    }
}

extension UINavigationBar {
    func getLargeTitleView() -> UIView?  {
        for subview in subviews {
            if String(describing: type(of: subview)) == "_UINavigationBarLargeTitleView" {
                return subview
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: а каким образом можно отслеживать состояние "большой" сейчас заголовок или "маленький" и ловить момент перехода из одного состояния в другое?

Comment: @xhr обновил ответ

Comment: а чем плох KVO? почему "KVO не предлагаю"?

Comment: @xhr KVO не плох, он очень даже хорош. Но UIKit его как бы "не поддерживает", подробнее: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html . А то что пока все отрабатывает - побочный эффект NSObject и когда-нибудь это может поломаться. А может и нет :)